# Possible function call overlay with javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an issue and I'm not sure why it is happening, so the title is a reflection of my comprehension of it.

I have a button that I press and gets data from a `data.php` file which gets data from database and outputs in `JSON`format. It is then displayed in a timeline inside my `index.php` page.

The first time I press the button, it loads the timeline and the data, but after that it only changes the data inside the timeline (`ajax`). The problem is on the second call of data and afterwards, the timeline starts to have very bad performance(slow, laggy) and even the font-size of the displayed data starts to increase little by little everytime I press the button. This seems to me like data is overlaying itself, adding on top of eachother each time I press the button to change data. Though if I refresh the page everything goes back to normal, restarting the cycle.

The timeline is made in `Javascript` and below is the script I use to load the timeline and display the data from my `data.php` file.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$("#okbutton").on("click", function(){
        var v1 = $("#cproc").val();
        var v2 = $("#estado").val();
        var tg1 = {};

        var doc_ht = $(document).height();

        $("#placement").css({"height":"510px"});

        $(function () {

            tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({
                 "min_zoom":1, 
                "max_zoom":30, 
                "icon_folder":"time/icons/",
                "data_source":"data.php?ty="+v1+"&est="+v2,
                "constrain_to_data":false
            });
            tg_actor = tg1.data("timeline");

    var tg1_actor = tg1.data("timeline");

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            tg1_actor.refresh();
        }, 1000);     
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Which timeline plugin do you use?

Comment: Hard to say when we don't know what happend inside `timeline()`.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: The timeline is not built by me it is a plugin from Timeglider which I'm just messing around with. I'm not very familiar with using jfiddle, can you make it work with files and database from localhost? The [first and normal load](http://gyazo.com/2aa3302c4aac15bd8d2ee88bc21a0ba9) and after [4 more times](http://gyazo.com/e8587a43cf452ece8659429509f94499)

Comment: Sounds like it's just not erasing the content of that element.... You could just try calling $('elementid').html(''); to reset the HTML inside the element before making your timeline call.

Comment: And how can I make it erase first and load the data after? When I use that bit of code after on the second button press it just makes everything disappear.